# GCloud permission error when deploying to Google app engine flexible

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to deploy my spring boot app to app engine via Jenkins using Maven. After maven has built the package, I am using "mvn install appengine: deploy" in the execute shell in the Build step. However, I get the following error when it is built,

```
GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/microservice-qa]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project.
```

Detailed error trace:

```
[INFO] Detected App Engine flexible environment application.
Sep 12, 2017 7:54:14 AM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy
[INFO] GCLOUD: Services to deploy:
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: descriptor:      [/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/demo-test/target/appengine-staging/app.yaml]
[INFO] GCLOUD: source:          [/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/demo-test/target/appengine-staging]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target project:  [xxxx]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target service:  [xxxxx]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target version:  [20170912t075415]
[INFO] GCLOUD: target url:      [https://xxxxx-dot-microservice-qa.appspot.com]
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...
[INFO] GCLOUD: ....done.
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: Beginning deployment of service [another-pub-sub-service]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: Building and pushing image for service [another-pub-sub-service]
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not have permission to access project [xxxx] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.198s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 12 07:54:27 UTC 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/51M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy (default-cli) on project demo-test1: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit(NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:30)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.syncRun(DefaultProcessRunner.java:211)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.run(DefaultProcessRunner.java:137)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runGcloudCommand(CloudSdk.java:193)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runAppCommandInWorkingDirectory(CloudSdk.java:136)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.deploy(CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.java:90)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        ... 20 more
```

I have checked the permissions in the server for the key/user used to run gcloud commands, they both have full rights. However I still get the above error.

Also, is there any other plugin in Jenkins or any other tool (like jenkins to manage builds and deploy to app engine) to do the same?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Jenkins Server might not be configured with your project, use following commands in your jenkins job configuration:

Execute shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
gcloud -q auth activate-service-account --key-file=${PROJECT_KEY.JSON}
gcloud -q config set project ${PROJECT_ID}
mvn appengine:deploy
```

Also, for 'gcloud' to be available on Jenkins server, you would have to install plugin 'Google Deployment Manager Jenkins Plugin' in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks @Sonal Aggarwal. I have done this in the command line where Jenkins is installed. However, running the 'mvn appengine:deploy' from the command line itself throws the same error. Unable to figure out what could be the issue.

Comment: Can you please paste the stacktrace here? Are you seeing same error even now?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the error even now. I have updated the question with the detailed stack trace.

Comment: Please check output of command 'gcloud config list --all | grep account' . Ensure that it is using same project's service account.

Comment: Yes, it displays:
account = qa-service-account@project-qa.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Your active configuration is: [default]. However, I am not sure what the [default] points to.

Comment: Check if same account (qa-service-account@project-qa.iam.gserviceaccount.com) is shown under service account list (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=PROJECT_ID). If not, change to appropriate service account.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the same in the console and it exists. I suspect that it is to do with the permissions granted for this service account, however I am not sure what to grant as I see whatever is required is granted.

Comment: Check for 'App Engine Deployer role' to this service account.

Comment: Thanks loads. Actually it was my mistake that after changing the permissions I did not download the keys again. Now downloaded the new JSON key and it works fine.